# How to always allocate static array with size multiple of 32

Tags: c

Is there easy way to allocate such array to be always size of multiple of 32, without modifying actual define? The reasoning is that if my_data size is increased i want the buffers to be always multiple of 32 but enough to hold my_data but without manual recalculation of size. Ie. if "my data" is 52 i want buffer to be 64 and so on.

```
typedef struct 
{
    char one[5];
    uint16_t two[2];
    uint32_t three[1];
}my_data_t;

#define SIZE_OF_DATA sizeof(my_data_t)
uint8_t array[SIZE_OF_DATA];
```

Comment: I still don't understand what the size of the structure `my_data_t` has to do with the amount of elements of the `array` of `uint8_t` and why do you want to code like that. Where is the relation between the both?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Can't we just assume akimata knows what they are doing? Without context we cannot judge if this "makes sense" or not, and more context is not necessary to answer the question as stated. There might well be architectural issues (but we do not know) with the code,but akimata can still just post it on Code Review, to be scrutinized. In the end, even sub-optimal code can solve a problem.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa OP asked for to solve a problem. The cited question can indeed be answered and solved, but not so the problem itself. This is an issue. If we want to really solve the problem, we have to know everything relevant about it. - "*Can't we just assume akimata knows what they are doing?*" - No. It is part of our responsibility to not assume this in the first place and if we would do so, over the half of the questions on SO would be answered the wrong way and probably not even answered at all.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I think it is perfectly fine to ask for more context if you assume this really is an XY problem at heart, on the other hand this question is quite concise and to the point, so I think answering it in the same manner is appropriate. I personally do not see my role here to be a teacher to everyone, especially if that is not asked of me, but I congratulate your approach. I always try to approach this with "let them make their own mistakes and allow them to learn". Maybe akimata will add the context to allow to "truly" answer the supposed underlying problem.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I know a decent range of users who just answer the title of the question post, but not the question itself. It is indeed absolutely appropriate to do so, but less helpful in some cases. I can't see the relation between both things here, that is the problem. If OP introduces us to the bigger problem maybe a completely different solution could be picked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your allocation size is `N`, but your block size is `X` (both positive numbers and `X > N`).

Then your adjusted allocation for N becomes:

`N = ((N + X-1)/X)*X;`

Hence, this is what you likely want:

```
#define SIZE_OF_DATA sizeof(my_data_t)
uint8_t array[(SIZE_OF_DATA  + 31) / 32) * 32];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do. The question is why are you doing it in the first place, though.

```
#define SIZE_OF_DATA sizeof(my_data_t)
#define SIZE_OF_DATA_PADDED_TO_32 ((SIZE_OF_DATA-1)/32+1)*32
uint8_t array[SIZE_OF_DATA_PADDED_TO_32];
```

Comment: Because these buffers are cacheable and invalidation/clean can be used only with sizes beeing multiple of 32

Comment: @akimata What has the size of the structure `my_data_t` to do with the amount of elements of `array` anyway? I don't see a reason for this in here.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with 3 simple calculation - like

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t getArrSize(size_t sz)
{
    sz = sz - 1;   // Subtract one to make e.g. 32 become 31
    sz = sz & ~31; // Remove bits representing values less than 32
    sz = sz + 32;  // Add 32 to compensate for removed bits and the subtraction by 1
    return sz;     // sz is now N * 32 and greater or equal the input sz
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%zu\n", getArrSize(31));
    printf("%zu\n", getArrSize(32));
    printf("%zu\n", getArrSize(33));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
32
32
64
```

To get it all evaluated at compile time, you can do as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DESIRED_STRUCT_SIZE 33   // Change this line to change the size of the struct

struct someData
{
    char d[DESIRED_STRUCT_SIZE];
};

#define ALIGN_TO_SIZE 32
#define ACTUAL_SIZE sizeof(struct someData)
#define ALIGNED_SIZE (((ACTUAL_SIZE - 1) & ~(ALIGN_TO_SIZE-1)) + ALIGN_TO_SIZE)

int main(void) 
{
    struct someData arr[ALIGNED_SIZE];
    printf("Elements in arr %zu\n", sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Elements in arr 64
```

Comment: As far as i understand, he wants it done on the preprocessor level.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz I'm pretty sure OP can convert this into (a single) statement(s) that can be evaluated at compile time. I think the important part is to explain to OP what is going on and how it works instead of just giving a magic formula

Comment: Well, not exactly magic, `n/32` is number of blocks without the last 0 to 31 bytes block included. `n/32+1` includes the last block. Since we do not ever want a zero size last block, `(n-1)/32+1` fixes it. Now just go back to bytes `((n-1)/32+1)*32` and you are done. TBH, i like this not-so-magic formula more than the bitwise method, cause it can pad to arbitrary buffer size, bitwise one can't.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it works in pure C

```c
#define SIZE_OF_DATA ( sizeof(my_data_t)%32? (sizeof(my_data_t)&~31)+32 :  sizeof(my_data_t) )
```

Also taking advantage of C++, in case you are using a C++ compiler for your C program by chance you should better better use a constexpr function, works for variables

```cpp
template<class T> constexpr size_t size_32(const T& my_data_t)
{
    return sizeof(my_data_t) % 32 ? (sizeof(my_data_t) & ~31) + 32 : sizeof(my_data_t);
}
```

Now easy to test

```
int main()
{
    char my_data32[size_32(my_data)];
    cout<< sizeof(my_data32)<< endl;
...
```

or for just any type

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    char one[5];
    uint16_t two[2];
    uint32_t three[1];
}my_data_t;
template <class T>constexpr size_t size_32()
{
    return sizeof(T) % 32 ? (sizeof(T) & ~31) + 32 : sizeof(T);
}
int main()
{
    cout << size_32<my_data_t>() << endl;
```

The following variant is strictly bound to your struct type

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    char one[49];
    uint16_t two[2];
    uint32_t three[1];
}my_data_t;

constexpr size_t size_32()
{
    return sizeof(my_data_t) % 32 ? (sizeof(my_data_t) & ~31) + 32 : sizeof(my_data_t);
}
int main()
{
    char my_32_data[size_32()];
    cout << sizeof(my_32_data) << endl;
```

Comment: The question is for C, not for C++.

Comment: Answering a C question with C++ code is rather strange...

Comment: See the first sentence, it is for C

Comment: @armagedescu That's not true. It is bad practice to compile C code with a C++ compiler and I know nobody except novices which do such cheese. C and C++ are very different languages. Many things which are valid in C, are not valid in C++ and vice versa.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio The bad practice is a very frequent practice of novice programmers. And the question of OP is not an advanced programming one

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Also check the first suggestion, it works in any context

Comment: @armagedescu You can hint how things *can* be easier in C++. But with "*in case you are using a C++ compiler for your C program*" you suggesting indirectly to use a C++ compiler to compile C code, which is wrong. Delete that sentence.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I am not suggesting anything. In 99% of cases a novice uses a C++ compiler when learning from a C manual. I reiterate, the question is not an advanced one.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Also be attentive. The correct answer is right in the first sentence of my post. Ignore all the rest if using pure C is a constraint. If not, then my suggestion is using C++.

Comment: "*I am not suggesting anything.*" - If your answer should be seen as professional, I get the impression you are implicitly arguing about to use a C++ compiler to compile C programs, just by saying it in your answer implicitly. If you would not recommend this technique, you wouldn't do so. - "*In 99% of cases a novice uses a C++ compiler when learning from a C manual.*" - I disagree with that. Any at least intermediate source of knowledge should be able to differentiate C and C++ and with that its respective compilers.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio In any modern C there is no C compiler that comes apart from C++. Any C++ programmer knows C and differences between C and C++. But in 99% if cases C is not a strict constraint to be followed.